# How to check if dynamic array is empty or not?

Tags: javascript

How I can check if a Mapped object is empty or not? Basically what I need to do is checking if there is any Array of Fuses in the `data`? If not, then do something else.

```
 if(e.attributes.display=='Fuses') {
   if((e.attributes.display == 'Fuses').length == 0){
      console.log("No Data For Fuses");
   }else{
      fuses.push([e.geometry.x,e.geometry.y]);
      }
}
```

```js
var data = [{
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "fieldAliases": {
      "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
    },
    "fields": [{
      "name": "OBJECTID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
      "alias": "OBJECTID"
    }],
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
          "OBJECTID": 649
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "OBJECTID": 665
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "OBJECTID": 762
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "fieldAliases": {
      "display": "display",
      "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
      "wkid": 4326,
      "latestWkid": 4326
    },
    "fields": [{
        "name": "display",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
        "alias": "display",
        "length": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "OBJECTID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
        "alias": "OBJECTID"
      }
    ],
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Transformer",
          "OBJECTID": 1537
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17602806699995,
          "y": 41.78431233100008
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Transformer",
          "OBJECTID": 1591
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17546081099994,
          "y": 41.783341919000065
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "displayFieldName": "",
    "fieldAliases": {
      "display": "display",
      "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
      "wkid": 4326,
      "latestWkid": 4326
    },
    "fields": [{
        "name": "display",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
        "alias": "display",
        "length": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "OBJECTID",
        "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
        "alias": "OBJECTID"
      }
    ],
    "features": [{
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13597
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17599727899994,
          "y": 41.78465526100007
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13598
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17595382899998,
          "y": 41.78455803400004
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13599
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17582231499995,
          "y": 41.78435312600004
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13600
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17561004899994,
          "y": 41.784005335000074
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13601
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17557576699994,
          "y": 41.78393182000008
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13602
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17535967199996,
          "y": 41.78352876900004
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13603
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17534426199995,
          "y": 41.78340020400003
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13649
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17450698899995,
          "y": 41.78350136200004
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "display": "Service Point",
          "OBJECTID": 13650
        },
        "geometry": {
          "x": -88.17435162999999,
          "y": 41.783597986000075
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

transformers=[];
service_points=[];
fuses=[];

data.forEach(function(el) {
 el.features.forEach(function(e) {
  if(e.attributes.display) {
   if(e.attributes.display=='Transformer') {
      transformers.push([e.geometry.x,e.geometry.y]);
}
  if(e.attributes.display=='Fuses') {
   if((e.attributes.display == 'Fuses').length == 0){
      console.log("No Data For Fuses");
   }else{
      fuses.push([e.geometry.x,e.geometry.y]);
      }
}
  if(e.attributes.display=='Service Point') {
      service_points.push([e.geometry.x,e.geometry.y]);
}
}
});
});

console.log(transformers,service_points, fuses);
```

Comment: Can you simplify your code/data structure to make it more readable for us? What do you want to test exactly?

Comment: Ok here I am loading geometry of a big data set to different collections based on attribute name. Now there situations that I am getting zero value for `Fuses` or for `Transformers` now how I can check if there are no values for them?

Comment: So the data does not have any where `display === 'Fuses'`, is that what you're trying to check?

Comment: `(e.attributes.display == 'Fuses').length == 0` this line doesn't make sense, value inside braces is boolean and doesn't have a `length` property

Comment: exactly, I want to know if there is not ant `Fuses` in this request then do something else

Comment: @11thdimension, :-) that's why it is not working! :-)

Comment: Do you want to check in the entire array `data` or individually for `data[0], data[1]`

Comment: So this is using ArcGIS for JavaScript API, right? You’re getting data from a Feature Service as well it looks like. Typically the approach is to loop through the Features in a FestureSet to investigate attributes. Sounds like you just need a loop that checks the display attribute to see if it === ‘Fuses’. If so, do something. If not do something else. What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: Thanks iCode, this is exactly what I need. You are right I am sending an `esri.request()` but the result is not in `FestureSet` format!

Answer (score 1):

The function below will build up an object of arrays (one for fuses, one for service point, and one for transformer) using reduce, and push the coords in as it goes. When it is done, you can easily check to see if the fuses array `.length === 0`, and if so, do what you need to

```js
function process() {
    data.forEach((el) => {
        let arrays = el.features.reduce(function(result, feature) {
            if (feature.attributes && feature.attributes.display) {
                // Get the display name to use as the key for our object
                let key = feature.attributes.display.replace(" ", "") 
                // Push the coords into the array
                result[key].push([feature.geometry.x, feature.geometry.y]);
            }
            return result;
        }, {
            // Provide a default object with empty arrays
            Transformer: [],
            Fuses: [],
            ServicePoint: []
        });

        console.log(arrays);

        if (arrays.Fuses.length === 0) {
            // Do what you need to here.
            console.log("No fuses");
        }
    });
}

var data = [{
        "displayFieldName": "",
        "fieldAliases": {
            "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
        },
        "fields": [{
            "name": "OBJECTID",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
            "alias": "OBJECTID"
        }],
        "features": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "OBJECTID": 649
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "OBJECTID": 665
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "OBJECTID": 762
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayFieldName": "",
        "fieldAliases": {
            "display": "display",
            "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
        },
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 4326,
            "latestWkid": 4326
        },
        "fields": [{
                "name": "display",
                "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
                "alias": "display",
                "length": 50
            },
            {
                "name": "OBJECTID",
                "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
                "alias": "OBJECTID"
            }
        ],
        "features": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Transformer",
                    "OBJECTID": 1537
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17602806699995,
                    "y": 41.78431233100008
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Transformer",
                    "OBJECTID": 1591
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17546081099994,
                    "y": 41.783341919000065
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayFieldName": "",
        "fieldAliases": {
            "display": "display",
            "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID"
        },
        "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 4326,
            "latestWkid": 4326
        },
        "fields": [{
                "name": "display",
                "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
                "alias": "display",
                "length": 50
            },
            {
                "name": "OBJECTID",
                "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
                "alias": "OBJECTID"
            }
        ],
        "features": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13597
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17599727899994,
                    "y": 41.78465526100007
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13598
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17595382899998,
                    "y": 41.78455803400004
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13599
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17582231499995,
                    "y": 41.78435312600004
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13600
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17561004899994,
                    "y": 41.784005335000074
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13601
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17557576699994,
                    "y": 41.78393182000008
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13602
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17535967199996,
                    "y": 41.78352876900004
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13603
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17534426199995,
                    "y": 41.78340020400003
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13649
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17450698899995,
                    "y": 41.78350136200004
                }
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "display": "Service Point",
                    "OBJECTID": 13650
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": -88.17435162999999,
                    "y": 41.783597986000075
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];


process();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check the fuses for each data element it can be done as below

```
data.forEach(function(el) {
  var hasFuses = el.features.some((e) => e.attributes.display === 'Fuses');
  console.log('has: ' + hasFuses);

  el.features.forEach(function(e) {
    if (!hasFuses) {
      console.log("No Data For Fuses");
    }
    switch (e.attributes.display) {
      case 'Transformer':
        transformers.push([e.geometry.x, e.geometry.y]);
        break;
      case 'Fuses':
        fuses.push([e.geometry.x, e.geometry.y]);
        break;
      case 'Service Point':
        service_points.push([e.geometry.x, e.geometry.y]);
        break;
    }
  });
});

console.log(transformers, service_points, fuses);
```